# Issue with whitespace and int literals / binary operators

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to write a grammar that allows for

- Signed integers (i.e. integers with or without a sign; `3`, `-2`, `+5`)
- Unary minus (`-`)
- Binary addition and subtraction (`+`, `-`)

Here is the relevant grammar:

```
expr: INTLITER
    | unaryOp expr
    | expr binaryOp expr
    | OPEN_PAREN expr CLOSE_PAREN
    ;

unaryOp: MINUS ;  // Other operators ommitted for clarity

binaryOp: PLUS | MINUS ;  

INTLITER: INTSIGN? DIGIT+ ;

fragment INTSIGN : PLUS | MINUS

WS: [ \r\n\t] -> skip ;  // Ignore whitespace
```

I'm finding a strange issue concerning whitespace.

Consider the expression `(2+ 1)`; this gives a correct parse tree, as expected, like so:
[image: The correct parse tree]

However, `(2+1)` gives this parse tree:
[image: The unexpected parse tree]

Since the `WS` rule means that whitespace is ignored, how is the whitespace here affecting the parse tree?

How might I fix this problem?

Comment: This grammar is ill-defined. (1) "fragment INTSIGN : PLUS | MINUS" is not terminated with a ";". (2) DIGIT, PLUS, MINUS, OPEN_PAREN, CLOSE_PAREN are all undefined. Please fix your grammar and repost if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the grammar is that you are trying to represent signed numbers as a token in the lexer. Define the INTLITER without "INTSIGN?". The grammar now works.

```
grammar arithmetic;

expr: INTLITER
    | unaryOp expr
    | expr binaryOp expr
    | OPEN_PAREN expr CLOSE_PAREN
    ;

unaryOp: MINUS ;  // Other operators ommitted for clarity

binaryOp: PLUS | MINUS ;  

INTLITER: DIGIT+ ;

WS: [ \r\n\t] -> skip ;  // Ignore whitespace

fragment DIGIT
   : ('0' .. '9')+
   ;

OPEN_PAREN
   : '('
   ;

CLOSE_PAREN
   : ')'
   ;

PLUS
   : '+'
   ;

MINUS
   : '-'
   ;
```